# Create Scoreboard using LibGDX table layout

Tags: libgdx, android

I am trying to create a card game, which will contain following features.

- It will be a 6 player game.
- Each player contain set of cards, where each card contain some specific value
- After every round a "Scoreboard" will be shown, that contains score of each round and total score.

I want to create a Scoreboard like below image.

[image]

I am trying to create it using LibGDX table layout, but the Table Wiki doesn't help at all for this kind of layout and I can't find any tutorials or examples on the web that would help.

Following are my code to create scoreboard, currently i am able to reach this far only.

**Score Board Class**

```
public class ScoreBoard {
private Stage stage;
private Assests assests;
Skin skin;
Container<Table> tableContainer;
private AbstractGameController gameController;
private ArrayList<Player> players = null;

public ScoreBoard(Stage stage, Assests assests, AbstractGameController gameController) {
    this.stage = stage;
    this.assests = assests;
    skin = assests.manager.get(Assests.glassySkin);
    tableContainer = new Container<Table>();
    this.gameController = gameController;
}


float sw = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
float sh = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

float cw = sw * 0.7f;
float ch = sh * 0.5f;

public void displayScoreCard() {
    if (players == null)
        players = gameController.getPlayers();
    tableContainer.setSize(cw, ch);
    tableContainer.setPosition((sw - cw) / 2.0f, (float) sh - ch);
    tableContainer.fillX();

    Table table = new Table(skin);
    table.setDebug(true);
    Label topLabel = new Label("Score Board", skin);
    topLabel.setAlignment(Align.center);
    table.row().colspan(players.size()).expandX().fillX();
    table.add(topLabel).fillX();
    table.row();
    for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
        table.add(new Label(players.get(i).getName(), skin)).uniform();
    }
    table.row();
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < players.size(); j++) {
            if(players.get(j).getPreviousRoundScoreByIndex(i)>=0)
            table.add(new Label(players.get(j).getPreviousRoundScores().get(i).toString(), skin));
        }
        table.row();
    }



    tableContainer.setActor(table);
    stage.addActor(tableContainer);
}
}
```

**Game Play Screen**

```
 public GamePlayScreen(Assests assests) {
    this.assests = assests;
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, width, height);
    camera.update();
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    FillViewport viewport = new FillViewport(width, height, camera);
    viewport.update(width, height, true);
    Gdx.input.setCatchKey(Input.Keys.BACK, true);
    stage = new Stage(viewport);
    stage2 = new Stage(viewport);
    stage3 = new Stage(viewport);
    gameDrawer = new GameDrawer(batch, assests);
    gameController = new GameController(camera, assests);
    scoreBoard = new ScoreBoard(stage3, this.assests, gameController);
    gameController.setScoreBoard(scoreBoard);


}

public void show() {
    //    Gdx.app.log(TAG, "Enters show method");
    Image backgroundImage = new Image(assests.manager.get(Assests.backgroundImageTexture));
    backgroundImage.setSize(width, height);
    stage.addActor(backgroundImage);
    InputMultiplexer multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
    multiplexer.addProcessor(stage);
    multiplexer.addProcessor(stage2);
    multiplexer.addProcessor(stage3);
    multiplexer.addProcessor(new GestureDetector(new TouchController(gameController)));
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);


    //   Gdx.app.log(TAG, "Executed show method succussfully");
}

public void render(float delta) {
    //Gdx.app.log(TAG, "Enters render method");
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.187f, 0.246f, 0.621f, 1.0f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(16384);
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.BACK))
        onBackPressed();
    stage.act();
    stage.draw();

    batch.begin();
    gameController.processGameRender();

    gameDrawer.drawDealtDeck(gameController.getDealtDeck());
    gameDrawer.drawDiscardedDeck(gameController.getDiscardedDeck());

    gameDrawer.drawPlayerDeck(gameController);
    scoreBoard.displayScoreCard();

    batch.end();
    stage2.act();
    stage2.draw();
    stage3.act();
    stage3.draw();

    //   Gdx.app.log(TAG, "render metod executed succussfully");
}
```

Below is my current output

[image]

I am facing following issues.

- Need a background in scoreboard table to display the text of scoreboard more clearly.

Comment: How does your current scoreboard differ from the one in the attached image? Have you had any specific issues while writing your code, which you need help with? If yes, try aiming your question towards that. If it's easier to explain the issue(s) with an image, attach an image to your question, showing what you currently (graphically) has accomplished.

Comment: @Daniel_1985 I have added more code, let me know if it helps.

Comment: I'm not familiar with LibGDX but I made a quick google search and the Table class has a setBackground() function, which should be of help for you.

Comment: This might be of help aswell: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39081993/libgdx-scene2d-set-background-color-of-table

Comment: I had already looked into that example, it didn't solve my issue.

Comment: Please edit your question and add information about what you've tried so far. By adding this, you avoid that other people suggest solutions that you've already tried.